# What is $\lim_{x\to-\frac{1}{3}^-}\left(\frac{1}{x}\left[-\frac{1}{x}\right]\right)$?

Tags: limits

> $$\lim_{x\to-\frac{1}{3}^-}\left(\frac{1}{x}\left[-\frac{1}{x}\right]\right)$$

How should I proceed if $[ ]$ is greatest integer function? I tried changing into X+ {X} but then stuck on fractional part function.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format the math in your post. It is rather difficult to read exactly what limit you mean to ask about.

Comment: Is there a reason why you couldn't just put $x=-\frac{1}{3}$ and obtain the answer?

Comment: @MattiP. The greatest integer function isn't continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $x \rightarrow - \frac 1 3^{-}, \frac {-1}{x} \rightarrow 3^{-}$.
So $\left\lfloor \frac {-1}{x}\right\rfloor \rightarrow 2$. So limit value is $-6$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\lim_{x\to-\frac{1}{3}^-}\left(\frac{1}{x}\left[-\frac{1}{x}\right]\right) = \Big( \lim_{x\to-\frac{1}{3}^-} \frac{1}{x} \Big)\Big( \lim_{x\to-\frac{1}{3}^-} \left[-\frac{1}{x}\right] \Big) = -3\Big( \lim_{x\to-\frac{1}{3}^-} \left[-\frac{1}{x}\right] \Big) =
$$
$$
= -3\Big( \lim_{x\to\frac{1}{3}^+} \left[\frac{1}{x}\right] \Big) =  -3\Big( \lim_{x\to3^-} \left[x\right] \Big) = -3\cdot2=-6
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer..